# Objective-C compareTo:

Tags: ios, objective-c, compare

Is there a standard mechanism for comparing two objects in Objective-C?

I know the `isEqual` method, but I am not looking for exact equality but rather **less than** / **more than** / **equal** kind of comparison.

In Java we have `compareTo:` that does it, is there anything like that in Objective-C?

Comment: Please define your object type? Is it NSString ? NSObject? NSManagedObject?

Comment: I was implementing generic data structure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Objective-C there's no standard protocol for comparison, like the `Comparable<T>` interface in Java, but some classes from the Foundation framework define a `compare:` method.

[`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare%3a) and [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/compare%3a) are some examples.

If you want to provide your own comparison method for a custom class, I suggest that you stick to conventions and provide a method with the following signature

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(MyClass *)object;
```

[`NSComparisonResult`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparisonResult) is an enum defined as follows

```
enum {
   NSOrderedAscending = -1,
   NSOrderedSame,
   NSOrderedDescending
};
typedef NSInteger NSComparisonResult;
```

`NSOrderedAscending` means that the left operand is smaller than the right one (and from this you get the others).

#### NOTE

It's worth stressing that Objective-C and the closely related Foundation Framework are **built on conventions**. They are not just an idiomatic way of writing, as sometimes the implementation relies on them. For instance if you instanciate a [`NSSortDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSortDescriptor/) without specifying a custom selector, the default implementation will call `compare:` on the objects. (hat-tip to David Ronnqvist for the example)

Another notable example is the naming convention for methods. Instance methods starting with `init` are expected to return an object with a +1 retain count. This was such  strong convention, that with the advent of ARC it [has been formalized](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#method-families) and built into the compiler.

To wrap it up: conventions are always important. In Objective-C sometimes they are fundamental.

Answer (score 6):

You should implement

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(CustomClass *)otherObject;
```

and return either `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedDescending` or `NSOrderedSame`.

Even though `NSObject` doesn't implement it, it is the method being used throughout the system for comparisons. For example:

```
NSArray *unsorted = @[[CustomClass new], [CustomClass new], [CustomClass new]];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" 
                                                       ascending:NO]
NSArray *sorted = [unsorted sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```

will call `compare:` on the "CustomClass" and use the results to sort the array. Note that if your class doesn't implement `compare:` it will crash because of this (when sorting).

Comment: Where is it defined, I can't see it in NSObject declaration

Comment: @foFox It is defined in classes like NSIndexPath, NSString, NSNumber and NSDate.

Comment: The answer is misleading. It's not a standard method you can assume any `NSObject` will have, as only some classes implement it, and it's not even a (formal or informal) protocol

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I don't agree. It's more rooted in the system than that. For example `[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:key ascending:NO];` will call the `compare:` method on your class to sort them. As with many things in Objective-C there are conventions throughout the system.

Comment: it's a convention, but you said to look for the `compare:` method. A person reading the answer would expect a standard definition somewhere, whereas there's not. Your answer is not incorrect, it's just makes a lot of implicit assumptions which you cannot expect a novice would get.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella is it making less assumptions now?

Comment: anyway the `NSSortDescriptor` is a good example of conventions built into Apple's frameworks. I added a note to my answer

Answer (score 3):

There is a `compare:` method in NSString, NSDate, NSNumber and other classes. They all return `NSComparisonResult`.